# Close and open windows with tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have a main window, and a button inside of this one, I open another window, which is closed by another button.
How is it possible that once the latter is closed you can not reopen it?
I attach the code of the two programs.

## FIRST PROGRAM

```
from tkinter import *
def funzBottoCli():import nuovaprova

root = Tk()

root.state('zoomed')

root.title("Gestionale")

bottonCli = Button(root, text="  Apertura altra finestra   ", fg=('red'),    
font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', command=funzBottoCli).place(x=20, y=20)

root.mainloop()

#SECOND PROGRAM
from tkinter import *
def funzBottoCli():fine_cli_ins.destroy()

fine_cli_ins = Tk()

fine_cli_ins.title("Inserimento Anagrafica Clienti")

fine_cli_ins.geometry('640x480+400+150')

form1 = Frame(fine_cli_ins, bg='red',width=640, height=50, relief='raised',        
border=3).pack() 

label1 = Label(fine_cli_ins, text=(" INSERIMENTO CLIENTI "), fg=('red'),   
bg=('gray'),   
font=('arial',16,'bold'), relief='raised').place(x=200, y=10)

bottonCli = Button(fine_cli_ins, text="      Chiusura finestra      ", fg=('red'),   
font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', command=funzBottoCli).place(x=260, y=400)

fine_cli_ins.mainloop()
```

Comment: see this link for more information [her](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009176/function-to-close-the-window-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open and close multiple windows. the proper way to do it is to create a single instance of `Tk` and then one or more instances of `Toplevel`. Your program should then exit when the instance of `Tk` is destroyed.