# Python 2.71.11 Tkinter window not closing "Application not Responding"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to open a simple file dialog to ask the user to select a file. The code I have is:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)
sys.exit(0)
```

The program retrieves the file name successfully, however the window remains open and does not close. The only way I can exit it is through Force Quit. I am using Mac OS X 10.11 and Python 2.7.11.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009176/function-to-close-the-window-in-tkinter

Comment: `Tk().deiconify()` before `sys.exit()`. So can't destroy hiding elements.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues based on your development environment.  See reference [2].  This worked for me:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk() #To initialize Tkinter, we have to first create a Tk root widget
filename = askopenfilename() # store filename
# root.mainloop() may be necessary for your development environment (see [2])
root.destroy() #destroy the event loop - only required in some python environments (see [2])
print(filename)
```

[1]  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm

[2]  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm