# Execute function, close window and continue with the next loop after pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to find a solution online but was not successful so I hope you can provide me a short and clear solution.

I want to execute the function `change_value()` after a button displayed on the window was pressed. After the execution, the window should be closed and the for-loop continued.
I am not asking for a way to close the window immediately after pressing the button which is absolutely trivial.

Thanks!

```python
root = tkinter.Tk()
variable = 0

def change_value(value):
    global variable
    variable = value

for iteration in range(0, 10):
    frame = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Button(frame, text = 'Button 1', command = change_value(2)).pack()
    tk.Button(frame, text = 'Button 2', command = change_value(1)).pack()
    print(variable)
    ###Close window and continue with the for-loop after a button has been pressed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to close the window in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009176/function-to-close-the-window-in-tkinter)

Comment: It is not a duplicate since the thread you are referring to just explains the mechanic of closing the window after pressing the button *without* (the key part) executing a function which is associated with the button first.

Comment: I don't understand the difference, sorry. Why can't you just put `root.destroy()` into your `change_value()` function?

Comment: Also, FYI your code has a lot more issues going on. `variable` is not being properly reassigned within `change_value()`, the `tk.Button()` calls execute the functions right away instead of passing them as objects.

Comment: root is used in other functions as well which are not listed here. I just want to close the current window without the need of also destroying root.

Comment: How about [`withdraw()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method)?

Comment: `command=` needs function's name without `()` and arguments - it is called "callback". If you have to assign function with arguments then you can use `lambda`  - `command=lambda:change_value(2)`

Comment: Thanks to @MichaelKolber and furas. You helped me out!