# Python Tkinter Closing Windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, exit

In creating a Python Tkinter program, I wish to create a button that will close the program. I have tried the

```
#with master = Tk()
master.quit()
```

method. And it did absolutely nothing to my program - apart from stopping anything from working, although I received no Tracebacks.

The other method I have tried is:

```
#with master = Tk()
master.destroy()
```

This again did nothing to my program - it did give me a traceback error though which was:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

My full code is:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

exitbutton = Button(master,text="Exit",(all the other personalization stuff here),command=(master.quit())) 
#or I used master.destroy() in the command area.
exitbutton.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

**None of the above methods have worked.**

Many Thanks
(For the future)

Comment: see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009176/function-to-close-the-window-in-tkinter)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to pass a function object into the command keyword, so don't use parentheses. Also you should be using the destroy function for TKinter.

```
exitbutton = Button(master,text="Exit",(all the other personalization stuff here),command=master.destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the function's name rather than as a callable:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

exitbutton = Button(master,text="Exit",command=master.destroy)##dont include the parentheses
##or I used master.destroy() in the command area.
exitbutton.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

- The only problem is that you are using parentheses`()` while passing the function(`exit` or `destroy`) to the `Button` as a `command`, Which causes it to be executed at the point where it is defined.

**Solution:**

- The solution is to remove the parentheses`()` while passing the function(`exit` or `destroy`) to the `Button` as a `command`.

### Fixed Code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

exitbutton = Button(master, text="Exit", command=master.quit)   # you can also use master.destroy
exitbutton.grid(column=0, row=0)

master.mainloop()
```

**Tip:**

- As importing all(`*`) is not a good practice, you should `import tkinter as tk`
  or as anything you want. The only change you will is to add `tk.` before each object belonging to `tkinter`.

Then your code will be as follows.

**Best Practice:**

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()

exitbutton = tk.Button(master, text="Exit", command=master.quit)   # you can also use master.destroy
exitbutton.grid(column=0, row=0)

master.mainloop()
```