# Tkinter window and pygame window open at same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to create a program that has a tkinter window open, and then when you push a button, it closes the tkinter window and opens a pygame window. However, when I click the button to open the pygame window, it opens the pygame window and the tkinter window stays open.

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Label(root, text="Start")
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: root.quit())
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I have also tried using:

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: root.destroy())
```

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", root.quit)
```

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", root.destroy)
```

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: root.quit())
```

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: root.destroy())
```

```
def start(event=None):
    root.quit()
btn.bind("<Button-1>", start)
```

How can I fix this? (I'm running Python 3.7.7 on MacOS 11.1)

Comment: @Rabbid76 If [this](https://gist.github.com/AlarmClockMan/63f7508cba928c5f7f68d28a185ed73c) is what you mean, then I still have the same issue. When you run it, does the tkinter window close?

Comment: What is you IDE and OS?

Comment: @Rabbid76 PyCharm CE 2019.3.3, and like I stated, macOS 11.1

Comment: How do I fix this problem then?

Comment: @Rabbid76 are you going to answer the question?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. Since you placed a bounty, you will get more answers. You have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue. However I recommend to use the *tkinter* window to a function or class. Call `destroy` when the key is pressed rather than after the main loop exits. Invoking the `destroy` command will cause and error if the application has already been destroyed, for example if the window is closed manually.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

def runTk():
    root = tk.Tk()
    btn = tk.Label(root, text="Start")
    btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: root.destroy())
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()

runTk()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I still get the same issue using this code.

Comment: In general the code should work. See [Function to close the window in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009176/function-to-close-the-window-in-tkinter). The issue appears t o be related to your system (macOS)

Answer (score 0):

I tried organising your code in a class, so it is a bit easier to make modifications to it and calling the individual components.

Aside of that, I changed your `btn` to use `tk.Button` instead of `tk.Label` (thought it made more sense in the context)

The actual toggle function calls the `self.tk_root.withdraw()` command. This effectively hides the root tk window - you can make it appear again by calling `self.tk_root.deiconify()`. If you also wish to destroy the root after you have hidden it, you can simply add a `self.tk_root.destroy()` after the withdraw.

Edit: If `withdraw()` isn't working for you, try to use `iconify()` instead.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pygame


class TkPygame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk_root = tk.Tk()

        self.make_tk_widgets()

        self.tk_root.mainloop()

    def make_tk_widgets(self):
        btn = tk.Button(self.tk_root, text='Start', command=self.toggle_to_pygame)
        btn.pack()

    def toggle_to_pygame(self):
        self.tk_root.withdraw()
        self.make_pygame_window()

    def make_pygame_window(self):
        pygame_root = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
            pygame_root.fill((255, 255, 255))
            pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()


TkPygame()
```

Comment: When I run `iconify()` (`withdraw()` didn't work), the window is minimized, and then immediately _unminimized_, and the pygame window is opened. When I call `self.tk_root.destroy()` after that, it does nothing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No sorry dont know why that wouldnt work for your, i cannot replicate the issue. I read a bit more about it, and it seems to be a known issue on OS X that you cannot destroy/quit the root without actually closing python altogether with something like `sys.exit()`